# Indeed authorization api returns invalid grant

Tags: php, api

I've been using the documentation of Indeed at https://opensource.indeedeng.io/api-documentation/docs/campaigns/auth/ to create campaigns.

```sh
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  "https://secure.indeed.com/oauth/tokens?code=MY_SECRET_CODE&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

And it returns:

```json
{"error_description":"Invalid grant","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

I tried to contact Indeed but nobody ansewered me.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason might be a misfit in the **Redirect URL** which is configured in your Indeed App vs. your Request for the Authorization Code.

Example:

- In the App/API Keys you configured `https://myapp.test.com/oauth`
  (check https://secure.indeed.com/account/apikeys)
- In the OAuth request url you had a slight different redirect url:
  `https://secure.indeed.com/account/oauth?client_id= MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somethingElse.com%2Foauth&response_type=code`

Matching them exactly resolved the issue for me and it worked nicely.

Comment: Thx @mhochm. I got it.